# Consider values from multiple columns into 1 final output

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

Requirement:

(Related to: MySQL)

I have set of unique names in column A, then column B,.. with each column containing a unique product.
Eg.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhlCV.png)

I expect an output, that considers the total of all Columns, under 1 single header and outputs something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2ljd.png)

Is this possible? How do I go about that?

Thank you!

Not really sure how to go about this. Would concat/ Union work here?

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: That first table is a real odd idea, is that really how you are storing data into a relational database. How on earth do you manage that?

Comment: You could do that with 3 queries unioned together

Comment: yes, its a tricky table, created way back.

Comment: I might be more than a little tempted to spend as much time as is required to refactor that into something vaguely sensible

Comment: UNION ALL + GROUP BY + SUM() will solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  person, sum(item) from 
(SELECT person_1 as person, shoes as item from YOURTABLE 
union SELECT person_2 as person, watches as item from YOURTABLE
union SELECT person_3 as person, clothes as item from YOURTABLE) 
temp group by person
```

Comment: I think there are 3 seperate columns called `person1`, `person2` and `person3` or thats what it looks like

Comment: You are right, I fixed the answer